# Enhancing Performance in SSAS Tabular Models with Physical Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have an SSAS tabular model, and the tables are currently generated from SQL queries. I'm contemplating whether the performance would improve by using physical tables within SQL Server, as opposed to relying solely on tables generated by queries. Currently, all the tables in my model are query-based, and I'm considering the creation of these tables within the Datamart.

Thank you.

Comment: When you "process" a cube you are loading a copy of the data (from the SQL Server) into a different kind of data structure (the cube) which is much more efficient for cubelike operations. If you point something like excel or powerBI at an SSAS instance hosting a processed cube, the queries are reading from the processed cube - ie, the copy of the data - not from the sql server data source. Using tables as data sources for the cube might speed up the time it takes to process a cube, but you would still have to populate those tables before processing the cube.

Comment: Are you talking about improving SSAS build performance by replacing queries with tables? Or are you talking about improving user experience by making the adhoc queries against the tabular model run faster?

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about delete queries that create tables on SSAS  (Query-based) and replace for tables that cointains the specific information, and bring all the table without queries. I think that the cube process will be improve!

Answer (score -1):

If your tabular model is in [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/directquery-mode-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions) mode, yes using tables (preferably columnstore tables) instead of complex queries is likely to improve performance significantly.  But not as much as switching to Import mode would.

If you're already in Import mode it's possible that physical tables would improve the Import/Refresh performance.  But they would not change the performance of users querying the Dataset at all.

Comment: That's right. I'm trying to reduce the process time for my tabular model, so I think that can be reduced if dont us query-based tables from SSAS

Comment: Sure, but you have to build the tables. This might not be any faster.  Have you considered  a partitioning strategy that will enable you to refresh partitions in parallel, and only refresh required partitions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/partitions-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: Yeah, we are considering that option, we tried to use it but the cube performance start to decrease , we believe that happened because the memory was physically partitioned.
I was traying to search a guide for good practices for implementing partitions but I have not found nothing yet

Comment: You should ensure that your partitions have at least 4-8million rows each.  Over-partitioning can definitely harm performance.